# what does setting kernel.shmall too high do?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'd like to know what the kernel does when the value of `kernel.shmall` works out to being larger than the total amount of available memory (main memory + swap space).  Is the value ignored and the default used or is it applied to the effect of "no limit"?

```
$ uname -rv
2.6.18-141.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 24 17:46:35 EDT 2009
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)
```